# Call WCF service in Universal app

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I use the following code to call the WCF:

```
ServiceReference1.service client = new ServiceReference1.service();
var data = await client.GETIDAsync();
```

But it shows me The remote server returned an error: NotFound.

Comment: It's missing a lot of details, it's very difficult help you. Does the server receive de request? What's your client configuration for the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The remote server returned an error: NotFound

When meeting this error, it may be caused by wrong service address that using in your client or the WCF service does not work.

If your WCF Service is the http service, please try to enter your service address in the browser to see if it works. If it does work, please try to check if you are using the right wcf address or please make sure that your wcf service is working. If it works when entering the WCF Service in the browser, you may need to use the [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler4) to help you capture the network data and do the troubleshooting.

Besides, you can also try to use another client like console client instead of the UWP client to see if it works.